# Xendesktop OS licensing

Tags: licensing, xendesktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Hi,

Suppose I need to provide 200 virtual desktop simontaneously to my users. Do I need an OS license for the 200 virtual desktops? I'm aware what VCED -> only for access points. But it's not clear to me how the OS licensing works. Or do I only need the OS license for the master image?

Licensing is a pain in the *ss.

Answer (score 0):

Read these:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/5/5059CBF7-F736-4D1E-BF90-C28DADA181C5/Microsoft%20VDI%20and%20Windows%20VDA%20FAQ%20v2%200.pdf
http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/8/4/78480C7D-DC7E-492E-8567-F5DD5644774D/VDA_Brochure.pdf

Basically you either need software assurance or a virtual desktop license for $99/year

Comment: OK, But this only seems to apply for the access to the VM's. Do I also need a full OS license for each VM?

Comment: No. You license access to VMs and you license physical machines.